# Chiaki on a Zero 2 failing on an egl error

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, opengles, pi-zero-w-2

I installed Chiaki on the latest RaspberryOS, using apt install, when trying to launch it, I'm getting an EGL error:
`Could not initialize egl display`
Every search I did found only developers suggesting to remove the dependency from the code, which I assume is not an option, though I didn't look at the app's code to verify.
`ldd` seems to find everything alright, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What is Chiaki? Got a link? Are you using Pi OS Lite or Desktop? Are you connected to an hdmi screen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://sr.ht/~thestr4ng3r/chiaki/ using desktop